# love2d body outline rectangle

Tags: lua, 2d-games, love2d

So I a question. How can I draw these rectangle with a gap in the middle,

[image]

What I want to do is to use a bounding box on it so that objects can move in the inside and collide with the inside edges.

I tried using a polygon but when I give this vertices:

```
points = {4, 4, 80, 4, 80, 80, 4, 80, 4, 4, 6, 6, 78, 6, 78, 78, 6, 78, 6, 6}
love.graphics.polygon("fill", points)
```

It makes a square filled inside, but I want a gap and I want the colliding box to only cover the red side. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use polygon that has "line" as argument 1 instead of "fill", use 4 coordinates, and set the width of the line to 2

```
points = {5, 5, 79, 5, 79, 79, 5, 79}
love.graphics.setLineWidth(2)
love.graphics.polygon("line", points)
```

That will draw the shape you're looking for.

Your description of what you are trying to code sounds a lot like [this tutorial on using love.physics.](https://love2d.org/wiki/Tutorial:Physics) and from my understanding love.physics doesn't allow hollow shapes to be drawn. So if you want to achieve the end result of the objects bouncing off the walls, I would go with what the tutorial describes and add 3 more objects that are similar to the ground object for the walls and roof

```
  --Wall left
  objects.wall1 = {}
  objects.wall1.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 25, 650/2) 
  objects.wall1.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(50, 650) 
  objects.wall1.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.wall1.body, objects.wall1.shape) 

  --Wall Right
  objects.wall2 = {}
  objects.wall2.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 625, 650/2) 
  objects.wall2.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(50, 650) 
  objects.wall2.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.wall2.body, objects.wall2.shape)

  --Roof
  objects.roof = {}
  objects.roof.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 650/2, 25) 
  objects.roof.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(650, 50) 
  objects.roof.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(objects.roof.body, objects.roof.shape)
```

As well as add the drawing part to love.draw()

```
love.graphics.setColor(0.76, 0.18, 0.05)
love.graphics.polygon("fill", objects.wall1.body:getWorldPoints(objects.wall1.shape:getPoints())) 
love.graphics.polygon("fill", objects.wall2.body:getWorldPoints(objects.wall2.shape:getPoints()))
love.graphics.polygon("fill", objects.roof.body:getWorldPoints(objects.roof.shape:getPoints()))
```